# How to configure database settings on TeamCity SonarQube plugin

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity, sonarqube5.1

I am trying to configure TeamCity plugin for SonarQube.

I downloaded the plugin to the TC server plugins folder and added a SonarQube server under project as described here in section Configuring SonarQube Server Connection:

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/SonarQube+Integration

What is the JDBC URL I should use?

Comment: Probably the same JDBC URL you configured inside of SonarQube.

Comment: @LarryShatzer, you are probably right. But I did not configure any database. I just started the SonarQube with StartSonar.bat

Comment: You should use a real database. The embedded one is not for production type use. There is a config file that has it. Read the documentation for Sonar on how to properly set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SonarQube default database settings can be found in this [section](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-Database). However it is recommended to use an external [database](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Runner#InstallingandConfiguringSonarQubeRunner-Installation).